# Linq selecting some fields in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to select some fields and send them to MVC View but it gives me this error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[<>f__AnonymousType6'2[System.String,System.String]]`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[IdentitySample.Models.ApplicationUser]`.

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var con = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var allusers = (from u in con.Users
            where u.Message != null
            select new { UserName = u.UserName, Message = u.Message });
    return View(allusers.ToList());
}
```

and in the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<IdentitySample.Models.ApplicationUser>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Message)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed)
        </th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PasswordHash)
        </th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SecurityStamp)
        </th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
        </th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TwoFactorEnabled)
        </th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LockoutEndDateUtc)
        </th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LockoutEnabled)
        </th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccessFailedCount)
        </th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailConfirmed)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PasswordHash)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SecurityStamp)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TwoFactorEnabled)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LockoutEndDateUtc)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LockoutEnabled)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccessFailedCount)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Because your passing an anonymous object to the view, not a collection of `ApplicationUser`. But this makes no sense - if you only want the `UserName` and `Message` properties, why does you view attempt to render all the other properties of  `ApplicationUser`?

Comment: How about `select u` instead of `select new { ... }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: because i sometimes i will need all properties and sometimes i will need only UserName and Messag..... How can i make that please?

Comment: You can just ignore properties you don't need and use ApplicationUser in both cases. Or for the case when you don't need all properties create a view model which contains only name and message, and pass enumerable of those to the view.

Comment: @Lucia, Then you need 2 different views - if you want to display all properties use `select u`, other wise use a view model with just those 2 properties and project your query to the view model (and the view will be `@model IEnumerable<youViewModel>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view needs `IEnumerable<IdentitySample.Models.ApplicationUser>` but you just provide  anonymous object by projection ApplicationUser in `select new { UserName = u.UserName, Message = u.Message });`

The best approach is using different views for different  proposes. In each view choose appropriate @model and provide details for that model in your controller method.